# `eigsh` (Lanczos algorithm) slows down for degenerate eigenvalues

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvalues

I have a complex Hermitian matrix of size about $70000\times 70000$. I want about 100 eigenvalues near 0. However, I know that every eigenvalues are two-fold degenerate. I found out that the running time of `eigsh` is extremely slow (more than 5 times) compared to the situation with no degeneracy.

Also, I found out from the following link
[Computation time of eigenvalues with ARPACK depends on what?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27805/computation-time-of-eigenvalues-with-arpack-depends-on-what) that degeneracy is bad to eigsh algorithm.

What can I do to make my code run faster? In the answer of the link suggests to increase the size of the Krylov subspace, but what size is the adequate one?

Comment: Are you using the shifting method?

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes, I am using the shift invert method with sigma=0.

Answer (score 2):

ARPACK recommends to use `ncv > 2 nev`. The default value of `ncv` would fit that constraint.
A couple of suggestions:

- increase `ncv` to 300?
- increase the tolerance `tol` to $1.0e-14$.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it soon and see what happens.

Comment: Sadly, increasing ncv does not help. Reducing tolerence helps a little bit, as it should be.